# Incorrect border for div while using resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a div draggable and resizable using Jquery and below is my code

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable();
  } );
  </script>

<script>
    $( function() {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    } );
    </script>


<style>
div {

  border: 1px solid grey;
   width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
}
</style>


<div  class="draggable resizable" >
  <h3>Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

Why do I get an incorrect border on the right and bottom side of the div?

Comment: Can you have a demo? I think if you add a bit of margin to the div, it should show

Answer (score 1):

It seems the "resize" added 3 child div elements at the bottom, right and bottom-right corner. So, your "div" style is being applied to them too.

So Change

```
 div{ ...} to

.resizable {  
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".resizable" ).resizable();
  } );
  </script>

<script>
    $( function() {
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
    } );
    </script>


<style>
 .resizable {  
  border: 1px solid grey;
   width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="draggable resizable" >
  <h3>Resizable</h3>
</div>
 
 
</body>
```